# How to use Promise in Sequelize Js to return a Entity

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

```
var user =  db.User.find({ where: { username: username }}).then(function(user) {
      console.log("Authenticate"+user.authenticate(password));
      if (!user) {
        return null;
      } else if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
          return null;
      } else {
       return user;
      }
    }).catch(function(err){
      return err;
    });
```

I am Using Sequelize JS with Node JS.
I want the object of the user that matches the where clause.
but when I do return from ***then*** function . but it goes into infinite loop.
I am new to Node Js and I don't know how to use Promise in Node Js.
Please help mee

Comment: The promises are fine your problem is somewhere else - where is this code in?

Comment: Show other code pls, Sequelize init and model

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33170094/320399 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/21716434/320399

Answer (score 1):

The return value from `db.User.find()` is a promise. It will never be a user, so your first line is incorrect.

What you'll need to do is call the next function in your processing chain from within the promise `then` callback. This is the standard practice in Node.

If you return something from a `then` promise callback it's assumed to be another promise, which allows you to chain multiple promises in a row ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174502/sequelize-limit-include-association/28332839#28332839)). That's not what you're looking for.

Your example would be better as something like:

```
function authentication(err, user){
  // Do something
}

db.User.find({ where: { username: username }}).then(function(user) {
      console.log("Authenticate"+user.authenticate(password));
      if (!user) {
        authentication(null, null);
      } else if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
          authentication(null, null);
      } else {
        authentication(null, user);
      }
    }).catch(function(err){
      authentication(null, user);
    });
```

Note the use of a callback to signify the result of your authentication test. Note also `err` as the first parameter to the callback, which is standard Node convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use try and catch block

Here is an example:

```
    authentication: async (req,res) => {

    try {

        let user = await User.findOne({
            where: {username: req.body.username}
        });

        user = user.toJSON();
        console.log(user);

       if (!user) {
               console.log('Not a user');
       }

  }

    catch (e) {

    console.log(e)

    }
}
```