# Sequelize: How to access [object Promise] or return value from promise?

Tags: javascript, express, nodes, sequelize.js

I have a situation where I want to access the user data only if he or she is logged in. I have the following code that works when I'm not querying the database. Meaning the `var tmp` is set to `YOUR_API_KEY`. But when querying the database, I get [object Promise]. I tried different solutions after googling around, but nothing seams to solve my question.

```
var tmp = function() {

   if(req.session.user) {

      return User.findOne({
         where: {
                    id: req.session.user.userID
                },
                include: [
                    { model: Apikey }
                ]
            }).then(function(sqlUser) {
                return sqlUser.Apikeys['0'].kay;
            });

        } else {
            return "YOUR_API_KEY"
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't. You only can return a promise, and "access" its *asynchronouy result* via a `.then()` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "callbacks"

```
var tmp = function(callback) {
  if(req.session.user) {
    return User.findOne({
      where: {
              id: req.session.user.userID
            },
            include: [
              { model: Apikey }
            ]
    }).then(function(sqlUser) {
      callback(sqlUser.Apikeys['0'].kay)
    });
  } else {
    callback("YOUR_API_KEY")
  }
}

//now you can use your function like this
tmp(function(apiKey){
  //do something with apiKey e.g.:
  console.log(apiKey)
});
```

Comment: Right, the problem is that I want to render a page. So the problem is that I want to wait to render the page until i get the APIKey. I want to wait until i get everything, but I also don't want to put the res.render('index', {... inside the promises, because it will get ugly soon.

Comment: @DavidGatti, you can render page first, and then get APIKey by using ajax request =)