# Trying to create an instance and multiple related instances in a many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am attempting to create an instance and multiple related instances with a many to many relation using a junction table.

While creating the multiple related instances, I need to add a value to a property on the junction table as well. I don't know if it is my lack of knowledge of sequelize or promises that is causing my problem.

The code I am using is below. This code does add the items to the database, but I need to redirect after the operation has completed, which is not working.

Basically, I need to create a Recipe. Once that is created, I need to create Ingredients and relate them to that Recipe. The ingredients are stored in an array coming from a form on an HTML page. While relating the Ingredients, I need to add the ingredient_quantity to the RecipeIngredients table, which is the through part of the relationship (the junction table).

```
global.db.Recipe.belongsToMany(
    global.db.Ingredient, 
    { 
        as: 'Ingredients', 
        through: global.db.RecipeIngredients, 
        foreignKey: 'recipe_id' 
    });
global.db.Ingredient.belongsToMany(
    global.db.Recipe, 
    { 
        as: 'Recipes', 
        through: global.db.RecipeIngredients, 
        foreignKey: 'ingredient_id' 
    });

router.post('/new', ensureLoggedIn, bodyParser.json(), function (req, res) {
    var recipeName = req.body.recipe_name;
    var steps = req.body.steps;
    var ingredients = req.body.ingredients;
    var ingredientQty = {};
    var currentIngredient;
    var ingredientsToAdd = [];

    db.Recipe.create({
        recipe_name: recipeName,
        directions: steps,
        FamilyId: req.user.FamilyId,
        CreatedBy: req.user._id
    })
    .then(function (recipe) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {

            currentIngredient = ingredients[i];
            ingredientQty[currentIngredient.ingredient_name] = 
currentIngredient.quantity;

            db.Ingredient.findOrCreate({
                where: { 
                    ingredient_name: currentIngredient.ingredient_name, 
                    FamilyId: req.user.FamilyId 
                }
            })
            .spread(function (ingredient, created) {
                if (created) {
                    console.log("Added Ingredient to DB: " + 
                    currentIngredient.ingredient_name);
                }

            ingredient.Recipes = {
                ingredient_quantity: 
                    ingredientQty[ingredient.ingredient_name]
            };
            ingredient.CreatedBy = req.user._id;
            recipe.addIngredient(ingredient)
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Added Ingredient " + ingredient.ingredient_name 
                + " to Recipe " + recipe.recipe_name);
            });
        })
    }

})
.finally(function(recipe){
    res.redirect('/recipes');
});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know that I am running into issues because of trying to use promises inside of a loop, I just don't know how else I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem that I was having. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716434/promises-in-sequelize-how-to-get-results-from-each-promise) helped me come up with my solution. 
I am posting the solution below in case anyone else runs into a similar issue. I created a variable to store the Promise from Recipe.create(), I used Promise.map to findOrCreate all of the ingredients from the form data. Because [findOrCreate](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOrCreate) returns an array containing Promise and a boolean for if the item was created, I then had to get the actual ingredients out of the results of the Promise.map function. So I used the JavaScript array.map() function to get the first item from the arrays. And finally, use Promise.map again to add each Ingredient to the Recipe

```
var ingredients = req.body.ingredients,
    recipeName = req.body.recipeName,
    ingredientsQty = {}; // Used to map the ingredient and quantity for the 
                         // relationship, because of the Junction Table

var recipe = models.Recipe.create({recipe_name: recipeName});

// Use Promise.map to findOrCreate all ingredients from the form data
Promise.map(ingredients, function(ing){
    ingredientsQty[ing.ingredient_name] = ing.ingredient_quantity;
    return models.Ingredient.findOrCreate({ where: { ingredient_name: ing.ingredient_name}});
})

// Use JavaScript's Array.prototype.map function to return the ingredient 
// instance from the array returned by findOrCreate
.then(function(results){
    return results.map(function(result){
        return result[0];
    });
})

// Return the promises for the new Recipe and Ingredients
.then(function(ingredientsInDB){
    return Promise.all([recipe, ingredientsInDB]);
})

// Now I can use Promise.map again to create the relationship between the / 
// Recipe and each Ingredient
.spread(function(addedRecipe, ingredientsToAdd){
    recipe = addedRecipe;
    return Promise.map(ingredientsToAdd, function(ingredientToAdd){
        ingredientToAdd.RecipeIngredients = {
            ingredient_quantity: ingredientsQty[ingredientToAdd.ingredient_name]
        };

        return recipe.addIngredient(ingredientToAdd);
    });
})

// And here, everything is finished
.then(function(recipeWithIngredients){
   res.end
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sequelize, you can create objects along with its associated objects in  one step, **provided** all objects that you're creating are **new**. This is also called nested creation. See [this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/) link and scroll down to section titled "Creating with associations"

Coming to your issue, you've a many-to-many relationship between `Recipe` and `Ingredient`, with `RecipeIngredients` being the join table.

Suppose you've a new Recipe object which you want to create, like:

```
var myRecipe = {
  recipe_name: 'MyRecipe',
  directions: 'Easy peasy',
  FamilyId: 'someId',
  CreatedBy: 'someUserId'
}
```

And an array of Ingredient objects, like:

```
var myRecipeIngredients = [
  { ingredient_name: 'ABC', FamilyId: 'someId'},
  { ingredient_name: 'DEF', FamilyId: 'someId'},
  { ingredient_name: 'GHI', FamilyId: 'someId'}]

// associate the 2 to create in 1 step
myRecipe.Ingredients = myRecipeIngredients;
```

Now, you can create `myRecipe` and its associated `myRecipeIngredients` in one step as shown below:

```
Recipe.create(myRecipe, {include: {model: Ingredient}})
.then(function(createdObjects){
   res.json(createdObjects);
})
.catch(function(err){
   next(err);
});
```

And that is all !!
Sequelize will create 1 row in `Recipe`, 3 rows in `Ingredient` and 3 rows in `RecipeIngredients` to associate them.

Comment: Ok, that helps, but how do I update the field on RecipeIngredients using this approach? When the Recipes and Ingredients are being related, I need to add the quantity to the RecipeIngredients row that gets created. The quantity is stored in the ingredient objects coming from the req.body

Comment: Oh, sorry. I totally forgot about that requirement.
However, I have to admit, I havn't tried this out myself, but if you see the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations) under section, "Belongs-To-Many associations", they mention that:
>To add a new project to a user and set its status, you pass extra options.through to the setter, which contains the attributes for the join table.
`user.addProject(project, { through: { status: 'started' }})`
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have seen that documentation. What I don't understand, is how to add all of the ingredients and add set the through value for them. That example only adds a single item. It looks like I would need to add each Ingredient individually. Which brings me to the issue that I have run into. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: `models.project.create({ name: 'Sample' })
    .then(function (project){
      project.createTask({ name: 'Sample' }, { through: { extraColumnOnJoinTable: '123' } })
        .then(res.json({ success: true }));
    })`  

Above code doesn't work. It creates a Project, then a Task and then a record in ProjectTasks (join table) but **without** the value of extraColumnOnJoinTable.  
I'm not sure, but you might want to open an issue with sequelize.

Comment: Do you think using Promise.Map might help out with this? I am not all that great with promuses yet, so I don't fully understand how to use the map or if it would work