# Many to Many Relationship Sequelize Node JS Array of Attributes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a Job Model

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, Datatypes) => {
  const Jobs = sequelize.define('Jobs', {
    jobinput: {
      type: Datatypes.STRING
    },
    typeinput: {
      type: Datatypes.STRING
    },
    jobdescinput: {
      type: Datatypes.TEXT('medium')
    },
    locationinput: {
      type: Datatypes.STRING
    },
    salarymininput: {
      type: Datatypes.INTEGER
    },
    salarymaxinput: {
      type: Datatypes.INTEGER
    },
    seniorityinput: {
      type: Datatypes.STRING
    },
    vacancyinput: {
      type: Datatypes.INTEGER
    },
    bountyinput: {
      type: Datatypes.INTEGER
    }
  })
  Jobs.associate = function (models) {
    Jobs.belongsTo(models.User)
    Jobs.belongsTo(models.Company)
    Jobs.belongsToMany(models.JobSkills, { through: models.JobHasSkills, foreignKey: 'JobId' })
  }

  return Jobs
}
```

and a JobSkill Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Datatypes) => {
  const JobSkills = sequelize.define('JobSkills', {
    skill: {
      type: Datatypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    }
  })
  JobSkills.associate = function (models) {
    JobSkills.belongsToMany(models.Jobs, { through: models.JobHasSkills, foreignKey: 'JobSkillId' })
  }
  return JobSkills
}
```

and a Many to Many JobHasSkills Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Datatypes) => {
  const JobHasSkills = sequelize.define('JobHasSkills', { })
  JobHasSkills.associate = function (models) {
    JobHasSkills.belongsTo(models.Jobs)
    JobHasSkills.belongsTo(models.JobSkills)
  }
  return JobHasSkills
}
```

and I was trying to do a create function

```
async create (req, res) {
   try {
     await Jobs.create(req.body, { include: { model: JobSkills } })
       .then(function (createdObjects) {
         res.json(createdObjects)
       })
   } catch (err) {
     res.status(500).send({
       error: 'an error has occured while posting'
     })
   }
 }
```

My Json data that i sent through postman is

```
    { "jobinput": "Title",
     "typeinput": "Part Time",
     "jobdescinput": "lorem ipsum",
     "locationinput": "California",
     "salarymininput": "0",
     "salarymaxinput": "1000",
     "seniorityinput": "Internship",
     "vacancyinput": "1",
     "bountyinput": "10",
     "skills": ["skill1","skill2","skill3" ] 
   }
```

I checked this answer [Trying to create an instance and multiple related instances in a many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420533/trying-to-create-an-instance-and-multiple-related-instances-in-a-many-to-many-re)

But I was getting the catch(error). 
This is my first project with node js and sequelize. Can anyone help me on this

Comment: error i get is SequelizeEagerLoadingError. and jobs table is created while jobskills and jobhasskills are not

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are not getting created than please use -

```
 sequelize.define(
    "Table Name"
    {
      Model Definations
    },
    {
        underscored: false,// Not Required in your case
        timestamps: false// Not Required in your case
    }
).sync({ force: true });
```

Once tables are created do comment the Sync option otherwise on every restart tables will be dropped and recreated.

Comment: Tables are created I use sync({ force: true }) while change in attributes or association. This error is not because of that

Comment: In your Jobs and JobSkills models declaration above where is the primary key declaration?